# How to exit a user input loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Well I have a simple for loop to take user input and creat a file with this input, then ask for the next input and create "file2" etc., but I can't seem to figure out how my user can quit the loop with a certain input (maybe "exit" or "end").

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=1

:runName

set /p names="Enter header for file !x!:"

for %%a in (%names%) do (>>file!x!.txt (echo %%~a) set /a x+=1)

if !names!=end goto:eof else goto:runName

:eof
```

echo press any key to close
   pause>nul

Ps. Sorry for the poor formatting,  I cant figure how to enter my code in the grey field from my phone and dont have a computer at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite shure why the input prompt says header.
Here is my best guess what you may have meant:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=1

:runName
Set "names="
set /p names="Enter header for file%x%:"
if not defined names goto :end
if /I "%names%" Equ "end" goto :end
(
for %%a in (%names%) do (echo:%%~a)
) >file!x!.txt
set /a x+=1
goto :runName
:end
echo press any key to close
pause>nul
```

Running

```
Enter header for file1:anton bertha caesar
Enter header for file2:anchorage berlin
Enter header for file3:END
press any key to close
```

File content

```
> type file*.txt
file1.txt
anton
bertha
caesar

file2.txt
anchorage
berlin
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! Can I ask what defining the first names variable does?

Comment: `Set "names="` ensures the var is empty. So when nothing is entered the var is undefined and this will be used to jump to :end. Btw in `goto :eof` this is a system label and should only be used as an alternative to `exit`

Comment: That makes a lot a sense. Thanks for the clarification LotPing.

Comment: `set /P` does not clear the variable if the user just presses _enter_, it keeps the current value...

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to figure out how my user can quit the loop

If you'll allow a suggestion, mine would be *don't do that*.

Almost any batch script is best written to accept command-line options and files as input.  Once you trap the user into providing input interactively -- anything more than `Y` or `N`, and even that's a nuisance -- you're putting him in a bad spot.  He can't re-run your script without going through the tedium again.  He can't use tab completion, or pick from a list.  He's trapped in a user-interface element that hasn't been improved in 30 years, and wasn't very good then.

I don't know what to suggest specifically.  The example you provide is so trivial it would be easier to provide the file directly using Notepad than to create it with a script.  Then you might want a verification script to make sure the provided input file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "SKIP=0 EOL=; TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%i in ('dir /b c:\windows\*.* ^|FIND /i *.exe') do ( 
 CHOICE /D N /T 5 /C YN /M "Please pre Y to exit"   
 IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 GOTO :END
 IF !ERRORLEVEL!==2 ECHO CONTINUE
 timeout 5

 @echo %%i
)

:END

ENDLOCAL
```